# Modify groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild in grails

Tags: xml, grails, groovy

Is it possible to append a node in 
groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild in Grails?

AppendNode does not work.

Do I have to use xmlparser or xmlslurper?

Best regards,
Peter

Comment: Do you have an example? Some XML we can try against? Some simple, repeatable code you've written that fails?

Comment: See this appending nodes - http://mrhaki.blogspot.in/2011/05/groovy-goodness-change-xml-structure.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely possible!  appendNode works but it's not especially obvious at first how to make it work.

In this example, we're storing HTML of a table in an object.  We'll parse that into a Node and NodeChild(ren), then append rows to it.  You could start at the second line of code if you already have your NodeChild, but I wanted to show how I got there in this example.

```
def tableContent = new XmlSlurper().parseText(table.htmlContent)

tableContent.tbody.appendNode({
  tr(class: "appended", "data-uuid": UUID.randomUUID().toString()) {
    tableContent.thead.tr.th.each {
      td {}
    }
  }
})
```

Note that you can also use .replaceNode instead of .appendNode, if you want to replace an existing node.  Finally, you can use mkp.yield within this whole block to output raw data.

In the end, we can get our HTML back using

```
String tableString = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind { mkp.yield tableContent }
```

and then continue to do whatever we need to with it.